# matplotlib setting on Anaconda 2 5.2.0 64 bit

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda

I am using Jupiter Notebook with the following configuration for matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook
plt.rcParams [ 'figure.figsize' ] = ( 12 , 7)
```

and with a 24'' monitor since long time.

I use the line of code "%matplotlib notebook" because it generates an interactive plot interface with the mouse coordinates reported on the right bottom of the interface itself.

On the other hand, the last line of code sets the plot at its maximum sizes without getting over the monitor itself (which requires the use of scrollbars inside jupyter and/or a scroll over the browser page).

Today I've updated my Anaconda distribution from Anaconda2 4.2.0 64bit to Anaconda 2 5.2.0 64 bit, my previous settings do not satisfy me any more and I would like you to help me with this issue.

According with the former Anaconda distribution, the code

```
x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.sin( np.pi*x )/(np.pi)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

should provide a plot with the right size for my monitor.
What I get on the new Anaconda distribution is reported in the following picture

[image]

The problem is not about the increased size of the plot itself, which still can be adjusted via the 'figure.figsize' setting, but with the display of the coordinates that are really far away from the graph. It looks like there is a huge amount of blank space both at the right side and the bottom side of the plot itself and the coordinates display is unusable in many cases.

Because of this issue, I decided to play around and see what happens in slightly different situations.

If you start a blank jupyter notebook and you copy and past the some lines of code, the magic function "%matplotlib notebook" does not work as you do not get an interactive graphical interface!

But if you run it again, the interactive graphical environment becomes active again and the problem seems to be fixed.

Moreover, for values of the first figure size less than 9 ( e.g. plt.rcParams [ 'figure.figsize' ] = ( 8, 7) ) I get a reasonable plot as reported here [image]

But if that value is greater than 9, than the previously mentioned blank space takes place on the right and bottom side of the plot.

I honestly believe that this is a bug, which can be turned around in some ways but still it is a boring staff to deal with. Would you help me to figure out a better setting for my matplotlib on jupyter notebook, please?

Comment: what happens if you do `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot(...)`? Does it fill out the figure better?

Comment: Nothing different than observed